# My PHP Socket Server keeps shutting down on Windows Server

Tags: php, sockets, real-time, windows-server-2012-r2

I started a PHP Socket server on Windows Server 2012 R2 by running the command: `php -q C:\path\to\server.php`. The problem that I have is that after several hours the server I am not able to connect in JavaScript. I have done hours of researching to figure this about, but since there is no errors I don't know what to search. My only thought is that it may shutdown from inactivity.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$host = '10.18.8.7'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (@file_get_contents('shutdown.txt') == 1) {
    $messages = @file_get_contents('C:\\Public\\messages.json');
    if($messages !== FALSE && $messages != "" && $messages != "[]") {
        $json = json_decode($messages);
        send_message(mask(json_encode(array('type'=>$json->type, 'message'=>$json->message, 'for'=>$json->for, 'permissions'=>$json->permissions))));

        file_put_contents('C:\\Public\\messages.json', "");
    }
    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'1', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode

            //DO STUFF WITH DATA

            break 2; //exits this loop
        }

        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'1', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}
// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg) {
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket) {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}


//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text) {
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port) {
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}

?>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I have run the commands in Windows Powershell, but I also have a PHP page that executes the command.

Comment: Probably not from inactivity, but something like a memory leak or an unhandled error would do the trick. How are you running the command? Just via the CLI manually?

Comment: @ceejayoz It is a pain for me to access Command Line, so I made a PHP page `print_r(exec("php -q c:\inetpub\wwwroot\os\\realtime\server.php")); ` to start it. Also as soon as the powershell window is closed the server stops. Think this might be why?

Comment: I would add debug output to all the important steps, (`socket_{read,recv,accept,write}`). It might be some IO-operation that blocks.